# ES5 Knockout to ES6 Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, ecmascript-6

I want to seriously learn more about ES6. I've been doing some examples online and although I get most of it I sometimes get confused to where to even start. Take note Im super noob at this ES6 and knockout stuff and wanted to learn more by taking an example of Knockout from their website and rewrite it to ES6. I tried using classes and extending classes but for the life of me I can't get it to work. Can anyone please show me how I would rewrite this below to ES6 with classes etc. If there is no need for it being rewritten then please let me know and also why. It would greatly be appreciated and help me learn more.

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

HTML

```
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: meal().mealName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first: your ES5 code will work fine in ES6 setup.

I don't have knockout at hand to test against, but the ES6-style classes would look like

```
class SeatReservation {
  constructor(name, initialMeal) {
    this.name = name;
    this.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
  }
}

class ReservationsViewModel {
  constructor() {
    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    this.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];

    // Editable data
    this.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", this.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", this.availableMeals[0])
    ]);
  }
}
```

For instance, `new ReservationsViewModel().seats()[0].name` will give you "Steve".

Comment: Awesome thanks a million! This really helped me understand ES6 a bit better when working with knockout along side it. I've place a copy of this online here http://jsfiddle.net/ga7ygwzp/